# EditText background not working in Android 4(ICS)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to set background to EditText widget, but this seems to be working in devices android 5 and above but not in android 4. In android 4 I don't get a border instead the entire edittext is getting covered with the background. The background I am trying to set is a black border around the EditText.
Code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/xfd"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/texview_border"/>
```

The `android:background="@drawable/texview_border"` sets the border around the EditText, code for it as below:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

The issue is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set solid android:color="#FFFFFF" in texview_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment that his works PERFECTLY.  Fixed my problem.

Comment: had a similar issue where i didn't specify the solid color at all once i set this to a transparent color, it solved the issue. However, ICS is still messing with my backgrounds, it sets my primaryColorDark instead of a custom color i've set